# My sprites aren't showing

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Im trying to get my sprites to show. Can anyone help with this? Please and thanks.

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{

    demImg = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Sprites/Demon");
    demrect = new Rectangle[rows, cols];


    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            demrect[r, c].Width = demImg.Width;
            demrect[r, c].Width = demImg.Height;
            demrect[r, c].X = 50 * c;
            demrect[r, c].Y = 50 * r;
        }
    }

    spriteBatch.Begin();

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(demImg, demrect[r, c], Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the only thing that shows is my background.

Comment: You're setting the `Width` twice instead of setting the `Height` in your nested loop.  Try fixing this line `demrect[r, c].Width = demImg.Height;`

Comment: It ended up working, thanks.